# Restsharp. How overcome Error Request Entity Too Large?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, restsharp

I have wcf sharepoint. And I use RestSharp client:

```
        var json = new JsonSerializer().Serialize((objectToUpdate));
        var request = new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, Method.POST);
        request.Timeout = 180000;
        request.AddHeader("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("login", _login);
        request.AddHeader("password", _password);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", objectToUpdate.ToString().Length.ToString());
        request.AddParameter("text/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);  
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
```

And  I get  error Request Entity Too Large.
I try add parameter maxRequestLength="{REQUEST_LENGTH}" in config wcf but not 
ineffectually.